# Find duplicated rows that are not exactly same

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Can i select all rows that have same column value (for example SSN field) but display them all separably. ?

I've searched for this answer but they all have "count(*) and group by" section that demands the rows to be exactly same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT A, B FROM MyTable
WHERE A IN
(
    SELECT A FROM MyTable GROUP BY A HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
```

I have done with SQL server. But hope this is what you need

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, which only references the table once, using an analytic function instead of a subquery to get the duplicate counts  It might be faster; it also might not, depending on the particular data.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, ssn, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ssn) ssn_dup_count
)
WHERE ssn_dup_count > 1
ORDER BY ssn_dup_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            MyTable MT
        WHERE
            MyTable.SameColumnName = MT.SameColumnName
        AND MyTable.DifferentColumnName <> MT.DifferentColumnName)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the required data and show them in order so that we can see the grouped data together.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE SSN  IN
(
    SELECT SSN FROM TABLENAMEGROUP BY SSN HAVING COUNT(SSN)>1
)

ORDER BY SSN
```

Here SSN is the column names fro which similar value check is done.